# How do I compile and run 32-bit Python on 64-bit CentOS 6?

Tags: python, linux, compilation, 32bit-64bit

I need to run 32-bit Python in 64-bit CentOS.

### Background

I have a PCI-GPIB interface card. Its drivers are from [National Instruments](http://www.ni.com/download/ni-488.2-2.9/2636/en/). It says in the drivers page:

> NI-488.2 version 2.9 supports 64-bit kernels. The driver may currently be used only from 32-bit applications.

### Using the driver from Python

I use [PyVISA](http://pyvisa.readthedocs.org) wrapper to use the driver, like so:

```
import visa
```

However, I get the following error:

```
OSError: /usr/local/vxipnp/linux/bin/libvisa.so.7: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

### Question

National Instruments says that their driver supports 64-bit kernels. **Good**.
But it can only be used from *within* 32-bit applications. **Bad**. My Python installation (which I compiled myself) is 64-bit.

#### How do I compile 32-bit Python in 64-bit CentOS 6?

Comment: a complete guide to your question: http://aresou.net/post/6/compile-install-32-bit-python-on-64-bit-centos

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I built 32-bit Python 2.7.15 on CentOS 6.10:

Install required packages:

```
sudo yum install libgcc.i686 glibc-devel.i686 glibc.i686 zlib-devel.i686\
readline-devel.i686 gdbm-devel.i686 openssl-devel.i686 ncurses-devel.i686\ 
tcl-devel.i686 db4-devel.i686 bzip2-devel.i686
```

Build 32-bit Python:

```
mkdir ${HOME}/{Archive,Build}
wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.15/Python-2.7.15.tgz -O ${HOME}/Archive/Python-2.7.15.tgz
tar xzvf ~/Archive/Python-2.7.15.tgz -C ${HOME}/Build
cd ${HOME}/Build/Python-2.7.15
[sudo] mkdir -p /opt/Python-2.7.15
CFLAGS=-m32 LDFLAGS=-m32 ./configure --prefix=/E/.sbx/Python-2.7.15 --enable-shared 
LD_RUN_PATH=/opt/Python-2.7.15/lib make
make install
```

Comment: This is somewhat close. Though I think there are many errors. you get the tarball in ~/tmp but then are trying to access it in ~/Archive. Then you make a /opt/Python-2.7.7 directory but then the next line the --prefix says use /E/.sbx/Python-2.7.7. Then the LD_RUN_PATH line says use /opt/Python-2.7.7/lib but there is nothing in that folder.

Comment: @RDT2 thanks for pointing out, fixed typo with `~/tmp`. `LD_RUN_PATH` will be empty until you run `make install`.

Answer (score 0):

If it's ok to run python from, for example, `~/tmp/Python-3.7.1`, the following worked for me:

```
mkdir ~/tmp
cd ~/tmp
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.1/Python-3.7.1.tgz
tar xzf Python-3.7.1.tgz
cd Python-3.7.1
CFLAGS=-m32 LDFLAGS=-m32 ./configure
make
```

And, of course, you'll need install the libraries & compiler for i686 first:

```
sudo yum install libgcc.i686 glibc-devel.i686 glibc.i686 zlib-devel.i686 readline-devel.i686 gdbm-devel.i686 openssl-devel.i686 ncurses-devel.i686 tcl-devel.i686 db4-devel.i686 bzip2-devel.i686 libffi-devel.i686
```

(added libffi-devel in comparison to other answer)